# Apache Spark - Controlling scheduling of map functions

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

I have a 3 node cluster and I'm trying to come up with a benchmark. The use case is that for an application all the map functions need to run on a particular machine and all the reduce functions on the other.

Is there any scheduling property in Spark through which we can achieve this.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The whole idea of spark is that you perfomr the same transformation on different partitions of your data in parralel executors. You don't get to choose which code runs on which node. At most you can control how to partition your data, but usually you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is possibly a very "bad" way of doing it.

1. Start master on m/c A. Switch on speculative execution.
2. Start worker on m/c B.
3. Start your application. Do map. Make sure you materialize (by calling rdd.count()) so it actually executes. Take your metrics.
4. Pause execution.
5. Start worker on m/c C

Running reducers on a specific m/c is more tricky. Because what you are asking is m/c B to be alive (for data) but not to participate in execution.

6. Write a function which will deliberately slow down m/c B. This function will also handle aggregation so that you can use this function in your reduceByKey.
7. Resume execution. This time, because m/c B is slow, Scheduler will be forced to launch corresponding reduce tasks in m/c C.

(This technique is showed by Reynold Xin during [2014 Spark summit](https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/slides/advanced-spark-training.pdf) to solve stragglers, but here we are using it to create stragglers :) )

As already mentioned, this defeats the purppose of Spark. You should not even try to do that. A hint: Spark != Hadoop MR :)